# Javascript Conflict In Two Files

Tags: javascript

I use a prototype in my project:

```
NodeParser.prototype.getChildren = function(parentContainer) {
    return flatten([].filter.call(parentContainer.node.childNodes, renderableNode).map(function(node) {
    var container = [node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && !(node.parentNode instanceof SVGElement) ? new TextContainer(node, parentContainer) : new NodeContainer(node, parentContainer)].filter(nonIgnoredElement);
    return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && container.length && node.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ? (container[0].isElementVisible() ? container.concat(this.getChildren(container[0])) : []) : container;
  }, this));
};
```

We have to add our client javascript file to our project. They have a code like this:

```
Array.prototype.map = function(fnc) {
 //code block
}
```

map in our code, return to them `Array.prototype.map` . How could I prevent such conflict?

This conflict happens in local only. In production there is no any conflict problem.

Comment: "How could I prevent such conflict?" Tell these guys to stop overriding native functions.

Comment: Map is a native method in array class.. overriding this will result in conflict..  use some different name to add method in Array class

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I know, but as they are clients, we couldn't say them such things :)

Comment: Or do not define prototype functions on native objects at all. It is never a problem to create custom object \ parser \ function \ module somewhere in your local code, so that you will never worry about conflicts in global context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only bullet proof solution would be to ask them not to monkeypatch prototypes of native object. Or at least do it in spec conformant way if they were doing it to polyfill native methods in older browsers.

```
if(typeof Array.prototype.map !== 'function') {
   Array.prototype.map = function mapPolyfil() {

   };
}
```

If this is not an option due to some contract obligations. You have the following options:

You can save native versions of monkeypatched methods before they did it.

```
 var safeMap = Function.bind.call([].map);

// usage
safeMap(myArray, callback, thisArg)
```

If they "only" missed `thisArg` in their map implementation you can make sure you always pass prebinded functions

```
array.map(function(){}.bind(this))
```

Or even monkeypatch their implementation to start Eternal Monkeypatchers War

```
if(Array.prototype.map.length === 1) { //was patched
    var theirMap = Array.prototype.map;
    Array.prototype.map = function(fn, thisArg) {
       if(arguments.length === 2) {
          fn = fn.bind(thisArg)
       }

       return theirMap.call(this, fn);
    }
}
```